# Failed build in Heroku master push

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy my project to Heroku, and my build failed. When it is deployed locally, I have no problem.  When I apply `git push heroku master` and look at the build log on Heroku, this is what I get.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> PHP app detected
 !     ERROR: Basic validation for 'composer.json' failed!
 !     
 !     It must be a valid JSON document compatible with Composer.
 !     
 !     You most likely created or edited the file by hand, and it now
 !     contains a syntax error. Please refer to the documentation at
 !     https://getcomposer.org/doc/ for information on the format.
 !     
 !     You can run 'composer validate' locally on your computer for
 !     further diagnosis. Remember to also always keep your lock file
 !     up to date with any changes according to the instructions at
 !     https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Okay, well, have you read the error message? "ERROR: Basic validation for 'composer.json' failed! It must be a valid JSON document compatible with Composer" seems pretty clear to me. Is your `composer.json` valid JSON and compatible with Composer? If you're not sure, we might be able to help. But only if you show us the file. Please read [ask].

Comment: I was able to find the issue once I pushed the files into my github repo and looked into my composer.json file per request of a fellow student . Found a red dot in front of my brackets which is not visible in vs code, but can see that there is an error(with no suggested corrections). Corrected the file by removing it, now working.